# Can someone help me understand recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

So i'm going over recursion in class and i can't seem to get my mind around it. Any suggestions to help picture the process?

From the sample test im doing:

```
class Q4
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        f(3);
    }
    public static void f(int x)
    {
        if (x > 0)
        {
            System.out.println(x);
            f(x-1);
            System.out.println(x);
            f(x-1);
        }
        System.out.println("bert");
    }
}
```

I see the output but i don't understand why it is the output. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to think about recursion is to start with the **base case**, and then see what happens when you apply the **recursive step** one step at a time.

#### Base case: f(0)

The base case here is when `x <= 0`. What is the output of `f(0)`? We can see this straight away because the `if` statement is never entered. The base case output is:

```
bert
```

#### Recursive step: f(1)

Now let's see what happens for `f(1)`. When `x` is 1 the code enters the `if` statement and ends up calling `f(0)` twice. If you substitute `1` for `x` in the function body, you'll see that the following statements are executed:

```
System.out.println(1);
f(0);
System.out.println(1);
f(0);
System.out.println("bert");
```

It's obvious what the `println` statements do, but what about the two `f(0)` calls? Well, we know what `f(0)` prints because we already analyzed the base case. `f(0)` prints `bert`. So the output from the lines above is:

```
1       // System.out.println(1);
bert    // f(0);
1       // System.out.println(1);
bert    // f(0);
bert    // System.out.println("bert");
```

#### Recursive step: f(2)

If you apply the same analysis to `f(2)`, you'll see that it executes:

```
System.out.println(2);
f(1);
System.out.println(2);
f(1);
System.out.println("bert");
```

And if we substitute in the output of `f(1)` at the two places where `f(1)` is called, we get:

```
2       // System.out.println(2);
1       // f(1);
bert
1
bert
bert
2       // System.out.println(2);
1       // f(1);
bert
1
bert
bert
bert    // System.out.println("bert");
```

#### Recursive step: f(3)

And finally, `f(3)` executes:

```
System.out.println(3);
f(2);
System.out.println(3);
f(2);
System.out.println("bert");
```

Substituting in `f(2)`'s output, we get:

```
3       // System.out.println(3);
2       // f(2);
1       
bert
1
bert
bert
2       
1       
bert
1
bert
bert
bert    
3       // System.out.println(3);
2       // f(2);
1       
bert
1
bert
bert
2       
1       
bert
1
bert
bert
bert    
bert    // System.out.println("bert");
```

Answer (score 2):

By looking at `f` and `x` we can see what `f` would do in those cases.

`f(3)` means:

```
System.out.println(3);
f(2);
System.out.println(3);
f(2);
System.out.println("bert");
```

`f(2)` means:

```
System.out.println(2);
f(1);
System.out.println(2);
f(1);
System.out.println("bert");
```

`f(1)` means:

```
System.out.println(1);
f(0);
System.out.println(1);
f(0);
System.out.println("bert");
```

`f(0)` means:

```
System.out.println("bert");
```

So putting everything together means we're getting interleaved outputs of numbers being decremented and `"bert"`. To see where each number or `"bert"` comes from you'll need to step through the recursive calls to see what's happening.

For example, you'll end with several `"bert"` strings in a row at the end but that's because each call to `f` ends with printing `"bert"`.

Answer (score 0):

Walk through the code on paper.

```
f(3):
    "3"
    f(3-1) = f(2):
        "2"
         f(2-1) = f(1):
              "1"
              f(1-1) = f(0):
                   "bert"
              "1"
              f(1-1) = f(0):
                   "bert"
         f(2-1) = f(1):
              "1"
               //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time `f(x-1)` is being called, a new local scope for `f` is created and a new local  variable called `x` is available only within that local scope:

Calling `f(3)` creates a new local scope wherein the local variable `x` is initialised to the value of 3.  Let's call this new local scope `LS1`.  Stepping through this method, we can see that `3 > 0` is true, so the method prints out `3` (first call to `System.out(x)`.

Then the method calls itself, but passes a value of x-1.  The first thing the JVM does here is calculate x-1, which is 2.  **Note that it does not assign the result to `x`; the variable `x` in the scope we have called `LS1` is still 3.**

What it does instead is call f(2).  This creates a new local scope with a local variable called x.  Lets call this new local scope `LS2`.  In LS2, we cannot access any variables from the LS1.  LS2 has its own set of local variables - new blocks in memory allocated for LS2 which are different to those for LS1.  The local variable x in LS2 is now initialised with a value of 2.

Again, we can now step through `f` to follow the flow.  The system prints out `2`, then calculates `x-1` (which equals 1) and it calls `f(1)`.  Again, in calling `f(1)` a new local scope is created (let's call it `LS3`), with another new block of memory allocated for its local variables.

The value of x in `LS3` is initialised to 1 and the method continues.  It prints out 1, then calls `f(0)`.  This creates a new local scope (let's call it `LS4`) with a new memory block allocated for its local variables.  `x` in `LS4` is initialised to 0.  Stepping through `f`, we find `0 > 0` is false, so that block of code is ignored. `bert` is printed out and the method exits.

The local scope `LS4` is now destroyed and its memory block (containing its local variables) is deallocated back to the heap.  Control has now fallen back to the local scope we called `LS3`.  Looking back, we can see that the last value of the variable `x` in `LS3` was 1.  The next instruction says to print this out, so `1` is printed, then print out `bert` then exit the method.

Exiting now destroys the local scope we called `LS3`.  Control flow falls back into the local scope we called `LS2`.  The variable `x` in `LS2` was set to `2`, so `2` is printed, followed by `bert`.

Method exits, destroying `LS2` and falling back to `LS1`.  `x` in `LS1` is `3`, so `3` is printed, followed by `bert`.  Method exits, and the program finishes.

Hope that all makes sense!

**EDIT**

Sorry, I missed the second call to `f(x-1)`  basically, at that point the same thing happens again; a new scope is created and the method recurs.

Answer (score -1):

See [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) is a method call in which same method calls itself.
So as in your code:

```
 public static void f(int x)
    {
        if (x > 0)
        {
            System.out.println(x);
            f(x-1);    //at this point it will call itself as f(2)
            System.out.println(x);
            f(x-1);
        }
        System.out.println("bert");
    }
```

It will keep on calling itself until the if condition is true. The very main thing you need to understand is the **Stack situation** of method calls whether it is recursive or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
private String returnType(int t, String[] s) <- return type recursion example
{
    String arrayed = s[t];
    if (t == 0) // <--if 0
        return " " + arrayed;
    else
        return arrayed + returnType(t - 1, s); <--if != 0 return value and then call itself again with the value -1.
}
```

It returns arrayed when it reaches 0. This goes through String[] s, and puts all the strings together side by side into one string